# Access ?wsdl of a SOAP API exposed in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a question regarding a SOAP API that I am exposing in the AZURE APIM.

I am exposing the SOAP API in the Azure APIM: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx, in the Azure APIM it is accessible through the URL https://minhas-apis.azure-api.net/ tempconvert/soap, however from the moment it is exposed I am no longer able to access their contracts through ?wsdl. I would like to know if there is the possibility of accessing all the contracts of this SOAP API exposed through "?wsdl", I have looked in several places but have not found anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

*I have added `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL` in the following way in APIM and able to get the results as well.*

[image]

[image]

Update the Backend URL from `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx` to `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx`

[image]

[image]

**Test Result-**

Pass the value in request body.

[image]

[image]

Try to configure the API in my way, you will get the result too.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I managed to get to this same scenario, but my question is how do I use the BASE URL(APIM AZURE) + SUFIX API URL(APIM AZURE) + ?wsdl to access the WSDL file of this API directly exposed in the AZURE APIM.

[enter image description here][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7bKb.png

Comment: @DanielGoldacker are you trying to access the file like [this](https://i.imgur.com/SCnT5Ic.png)